# Excel VBA Timestamp not updating

Tags: vba, excel, timestamp

I have a worksheet I am building that will track our incoming trailers and put that information on a dashboard. I have VBA setup that when the user changes the cell in Column A from Here to Closed, it will copy that line to the next sheet that will keep a history of trailers.

My problem is the VBA timestamp on the completed page is not updating when the line is copied over. I know the vba works as I can change the Trailer number on the completed sheet and it will trigger the vba and a timestamp will appear. But I need that timestamp to appear when the line is copied from the dashboard sheet.

Am I missing something that I need to turn on that will help trigger the timestamp?

Thanks

Edit- Sorry I didn't add in the code. Here is what I have for the Timestamp on the Completed Sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C10000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target = "" Then Exit Sub

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    With Cells(Target.Row, 10)
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    End With
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Code for my dashboard page that will copy the line over

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A5000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target = "" Then Exit Sub

Dim NR As Long

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Closed"
          Range("A" & Target.Row & ":z" & Target.Row).Copy _
          Worksheets("Completed").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
          Target.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End Select
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The one thing your missing, is the source code for us to help you. We are good, but not genies. Please post your source code and we will be better able to assist you.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you expect? Who or what should change anything on the `Completed` sheet when you copy a row over? Clearly the sub to copy a row includes the line `.EnableEvents = False`. So, the other sub won't run. And that's good. So, if you want to change anything on the sheet `Completed` after the row has been copied over then I'd suggest that you include that bit into the sub which copies over that row.

Comment: You say you are copying a line over but the macro exits if >1 cells is are in the target range (If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub). It's likely it's not firing because of this.

Comment: @Flephal It won't run because events are disabled.

Comment: @Ralph No - that's not true; EnableEvents = False is required because adding the timestamp will trigger a further change event otherwise, so that coding is correct.

Comment: @RabidWookie Add Debug.Print "Got Here" before the With Application event to show whether it exits or not when a line is added...

Comment: @Ralph I am not sure I am tracking what you are referencing when you say that I need to include the bit into the sub which copies over the row.

Comment: @Flephal You said that `EnableEvents = False is required`. Yet, that's exactly what the OP is wondering about: why that event isn't firing and updating the date. The **second** `Worksheet_Change` in the above post is copying over a row from the "master sheet" to the "completed" sheet and then the **first** `Worksheet_Change` should update the date (after it has been copied over by the second `Worksheet_Change`). But that won't happen because events are disabled while the second `Worksheet_Change` runs.

Comment: @Flephal I added the line you suggested, but nothing changed.

Comment: @RabidWookie ,  Do you have just two sheets, one for current trucks on your lot and another for a history of all trucks that have been on the lot?  And when the user marks col A closed, it moves that row to the history sheet?  If so then the logic is simpler than what's in your code.  Everything can be controlled from current sheet code.  Here is quasi logic-code - if target = "Closed" then move target row to first available row of history sheet and delete it from current sheet.  Set "Here" time with SomeCol = Now. Set "Closed" time with SomeOtherCol = Now.

Comment: Perhaps this will help. I've screenshot my workbook into the following two images

Dashboard page
[link](http://i.imgur.com/Qspy67t.png)

Completed Page
[link](http://i.imgur.com/qbQ8g3W.png)

The Miller sheet wont have any vba coding for it as it is just for one specific company that delivers cardboard and the Sheet1 page is my notes page

Comment: @Ralph Ah - I see what you're saying; I was only considering the first block of code... However I still think enabling events for the second code block still won't work as expected as the target range in the first code block will be greater than 1 cell - two things to fix here (yes - events would need to be enable for the second block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with. I don't see why you need to have two worksheet functions when one would suffice. Place this code in the dashboard worksheet and it will copy and paste to the Completed worksheet. There are a few things I added to the code. Firstly, error handling, if there is an error and `.EnableEvents = False` is one of the last line that executes, subsequent events will not fire and you will not be happy with yourself. I also added a few `End If`  which seem to be missing from your code. I added some comments to the code so that you understand where I made the changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

If Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A5000")) Is Nothing _
   Then Exit Sub
If Target.Count > 1 Then
   Exit Sub
End If

If Target = "" Then
   Exit Sub
End If

Dim NR As Long
With Application
  .EnableEvents = False
  .ScreenUpdating = False
  Select Case Target.Value
    Case "Closed"
      Range("A" & Target.Row & ":z" & Target.Row).Copy _
      Worksheets("Completed").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
      'get the last cell used.
      Set lastCell = Worksheets("Completed").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
      'new line of code
      lastCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = Now
      lastCell.Offset(0, 10).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
      Target.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End Select
  .EnableEvents = True
  .ScreenUpdating = True

End With

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "You have encountered an error. Please notify admin"
End Sub
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I edited your solution, but you copied the `OffSet` from the original post incorrectly. There the offset is 10 columns and not 1 column. Also, I added the `NumberFormat` from the original post.

Comment: @Ralph, my bad Ralph, and thank you for updating. I think the original post most of had that information or perhaps I simply copied the information wrong. Thanks for updating !

Comment: @Miguel That code is awesome! Thank you! Ralph and Flephal, Thank you for all the help too!

Comment: @RabidWookie glad to help mate. Cheers! Don't forget to mark it as answered!